# CUBLAS error after performing cublasSgemmBatched

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

In my CUDA/C++ code , I want to multiply A matrix( batched of 1*2 matrix s) with F matrix( 2*2) and get the result. I used cublasSgemmBatched function for that. But whenever I try to get the result(using cublasGetMatrix) after SgemmBatched, I get an CUBLAS error.

Can anyone figure out the mistake that I am doing here?

Thank you

```
int main() {
 cublasHandle_t handle; cublasCreate(&handle);

float ** F;float ** F_dev;
float result[1][2]={0,0}; float data [2][2]={2,0,3,0};


F =(float **)malloc(1 * sizeof(*F));if (F == NULL){ perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
      checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **) F, 2*2* sizeof(float)));
      checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **) &F_dev, 1 * sizeof(*F)));
      checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(F_dev, F, 1 * sizeof(*F), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));


// Linear dimension of matrices
int row = 1; int col  =2;

int batch_count = 2;

   float **A;
   A = (float**)malloc(batch_count*sizeof(float*));
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<batch_count; i++) {
       A[i] = (float*)malloc(row*col*sizeof(float));

   }

   // initializing A[i]
   for(int k=0;k<row*col;k++){
   (A[0])[k]=23;(A[1])[k]=67;
   }
   // Create host pointer array to device matrix storage
   float **d_A; float **h_d_A;

   h_d_A = (float**)malloc(batch_count*sizeof(float*));

   for(i=0; i<batch_count; i++) {
       checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&h_d_A[i], row*col*sizeof(float)));

   }


   checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, batch_count*sizeof(float*)));
   checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_d_A, batch_count*sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

   cublascall(cublasSetMatrix(2, 2, sizeof(float), data, 2, F[0], 2)); //filling F_array in device
   cublascall(cublasSetMatrix(row, col, sizeof(float), A[0], row, h_d_A[0], row));
  cublascall(cublasSetMatrix(row, col, sizeof(float), A[1], row, h_d_A[1], row));

   float al =1; float bet=0;

   // A-> 1*2 F ->2*2
  cublascall(cublasSgemmBatched(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,1,2,2,&al,(const float**)d_A,1,(const float**)F_dev,2,&bet,d_A,1,2)  );
  cublascall(cublasGetMatrix(row, col, sizeof(float), h_d_A[0], 1, result, 1)); // IM GETTING ERROR



 cout <<  "answer \n " ;

     for (int j=0; j<2;j++){
         cout << result[j];
         cout<<"\n";
         }
```

}

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743384/how-performing-multiple-matrix-multiplications-in-cuda) is a fully worked batched gemm example.  Do you want to look through it?

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella , I will look through it and try to figure out my mistake

Comment: BTW, can we use SgemmBatched to multiply batched matrix with a   single matrix(non batched) ?

Comment: Yes, and the suggested method is covered in the question I linked.  Basically, for the array of pointers for the second (single) matrix, you would pass an array with all pointers pointing to the same matrix.

Comment: What CUBLAS error is reported?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks alot, you just saved my day. that code worked !!!