# error using cublasSgemmBatched in mex

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex, cublas

I am trying to multiply Multiple Matrices from within matlab using cublasSgemmBatched in a mex file.

My matlab code is very simple:

```
gpuDevice(1);
a = single(rand(400,10,1500,'gpuArray'));
b = single(rand(10,12,1500,'gpuArray'));
c = MatCuda(a,b)
```

I get the following error:

Error using gpuArray/subsref
An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
unknown error

and here's the mexFunction code:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){

char const * const errId = "parallel:gpu:mexGPUExample:InvalidInput";
char const * const errMsg = "Invalid input to MEX file.";

/* Declare all variables.*/
mxGPUArray const *A;
mxGPUArray const *B;
mxGPUArray *C;

/* Initialize the MathWorks GPU API. */
mxInitGPU();

/* Throw an error if the input is not a GPU array. */
if ((nrhs != 2) || !(mxIsGPUArray(prhs[0])) || !(mxIsGPUArray(prhs[1]))) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(errId, errMsg);
}

A = mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]);
B = mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[1]);

if ((mxGPUGetClassID(A) != mxSINGLE_CLASS) || (mxGPUGetClassID(B) != mxSINGLE_CLASS)) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(errId, errMsg);
}

float const *d_A;
float const *d_B;
d_A = (float const *)(mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(A));
d_B = (float const *)(mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(B));

const mwSize *dimsA = mxGPUGetDimensions(A);
size_t nrowsA = dimsA[0];
size_t ncolsA = dimsA[1];
size_t nMatricesA = dimsA[2];
mxFree((void*) dimsA);

const mwSize *dimsB = mxGPUGetDimensions(B);
size_t nrowsB = dimsB[0];
size_t ncolsB = dimsB[1];
size_t nMatricesB = dimsB[2];
mxFree((void*)dimsB);

size_t nrowsC = nrowsA;
size_t ncolsC = ncolsB;

mwSize dimsC[3] = { nrowsA, ncolsB, nMatricesB };
C = mxGPUCreateGPUArray(mxGPUGetNumberOfDimensions(A),
    dimsC,
    mxGPUGetClassID(A),
    mxGPUGetComplexity(A),
    MX_GPU_DO_NOT_INITIALIZE);

float *d_C;
d_C = (float *)(mxGPUGetData(C));

cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasStatus_t ret;
ret = cublasCreate(&handle);
if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("cublasCreate returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
const float alpha = 1.0f;
const float beta = 0.0f;
ret = cublasSgemmBatched(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, nrowsA, ncolsB, ncolsA, &alpha, &d_A, nrowsA, &d_B, nrowsB, &beta, &d_C, nrowsC, nMatricesA);

if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("cublasSgemm returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ret = cublasDestroy(handle);
if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("cublasCreate returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(C);
mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(A);
mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(B);
mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(C);
}
```

I suspect it's related to the function cublasSgemmBatched because when I remove it from the code then I don't get the error.

Help will be very much appreciated !
Thanks !

Comment: gemmBatched is more complicated than most cublas functions to use.  Not only do you have to copy the arrays of matrices to multiply, but you must also copy arrays of pointers to these matrices.    You might test your understanding by writing an ordinary C/C++ code that utilizes the function correctly, or else take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743384/how-performing-multiple-matrix-multiplications-in-cuda/23743838#23743838).

Comment: You haven't grasped the requirements of the gemmBatched function, and so your invocation is certainly incorrect.  We do not pass the (host) address of a device pointer for the parameters where you have `d_A`, `d_B`, and `d_C`.  These are pointer-to-pointer parameters, and they must be properly set up as an array of device pointers that are then copied to the device.  I think your approach is missing this point altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a MEX file here, you can use [`pagefun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pagefun.html) to do this. Also, I'd recommend building `a` and `b` in `single` precision directly rather than casting. In other words,

```
a = rand(400,10,1500,'single','gpuArray');
b = rand(10,12,1500,'single','gpuArray');
c = pagefun(@mtimes, a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

cublasDgemm works for me. I just pass regular arrays to the mexfunction. Here is my example code.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "mxGPUArray.h"

typedef struct _matrixSize
{
    unsigned int uiWA, uiHA, uiWB, uiHB, uiWC, uiHC;
} sMatrixSize;

void matrixMultiply(double const* d_A, double const* d_B, double* d_C, sMatrixSize &matrix_size);

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])
{
    mxGPUArray const *A;
    mxGPUArray const *B;
    mxGPUArray *C;
    _matrixSize matrix_size;
    mwSize const *A_sz;
    mwSize const *B_sz;

    double const *d_A;
    double const *d_B;
    double *d_C;

    char const * const errId = "parallel:gpu:mexGPUExample:InvalidInput";
    char const * const errMsg = "Invalid input to MEX file.";

    if (nrhs != 2) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Need two inputs");
    }

    A = mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]);
    B = mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[1]);

    A_sz=mxGPUGetDimensions(A);
    B_sz = mxGPUGetDimensions(B);

    matrix_size.uiWA = (unsigned int)A_sz[0]; matrix_size.uiHA = (unsigned int)A_sz[1];
    matrix_size.uiWB = (unsigned int)B_sz[0]; matrix_size.uiHB = (unsigned int)B_sz[1];
    mwSize C_sz[3] = { matrix_size.uiWA, matrix_size.uiHB, 1 };

    d_A = (double const *)(mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(A));
    d_B = (double const *)(mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(B));

    C = mxGPUCreateGPUArray(mxGPUGetNumberOfDimensions(A),
        C_sz,
        mxGPUGetClassID(A),
        mxGPUGetComplexity(A),
        MX_GPU_DO_NOT_INITIALIZE);

    d_C = (double *)(mxGPUGetData(C));

    matrixMultiply(d_A, d_B, d_C, matrix_size);
    plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(C);

    mxFree((void*)A_sz);
    mxFree((void*)B_sz);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(A);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(B);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(C);
}

void matrixMultiply(double const* d_A, double const* d_B, double* d_C, sMatrixSize &matrix_size)
{
    cublasStatus_t status;
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    status=cublasCreate(&handle);
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (status == CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED) {
            mexPrintf("CUBLAS initializing error");
        }
        getchar();
        return;
    }
    const double alpha = 1.0f;
    const double beta = 0.0f;
    cublasDgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, matrix_size.uiWB, matrix_size.uiHA, matrix_size.uiWA, &alpha, d_B, matrix_size.uiWB, d_A, matrix_size.uiWA, &beta, d_C, matrix_size.uiWB);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cublasDestroy(handle);
}
```

There is also a more native cuda style. Both works fine for me.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "mxGPUArray.h"

typedef struct _matrixSize
{
    unsigned int uiWA, uiHA, uiWB, uiHB, uiWC, uiHC;
} sMatrixSize;

void matrixMultiply(double const* d_A, double const* d_B, double* d_C, sMatrixSize &matrix_size);

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])
{
    mxArray const *mA;
    mxArray const *mB;

    _matrixSize matrix_size;
    size_t A_w, A_h, B_w, B_h;

    double *d_A;
    double *d_B;
    double *d_C;

    double *h_A;
    double *h_B;
    double *h_C;

    char const * const errId = "parallel:gpu:mexGPUExample:InvalidInput";
    char const * const errMsg = "Invalid input to MEX file.";

    if (nrhs != 2) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Need two inputs");
    }

    mA = prhs[0]; mB = prhs[1];
    A_w = mxGetM(mA);A_h = mxGetN(mA);B_w = mxGetM(mB);B_h = mxGetN(mB);

    matrix_size.uiWA = (unsigned int)A_w; matrix_size.uiHA = (unsigned int)A_h;
    matrix_size.uiWB = (unsigned int)B_w; matrix_size.uiHB = (unsigned int)B_h;
    matrix_size.uiWC = (unsigned int)A_w; matrix_size.uiHC = (unsigned int)B_h;

    mwSize const C_sz[3] = { matrix_size.uiWA, matrix_size.uiHB, 1 };

    unsigned int size_A = matrix_size.uiWA * matrix_size.uiHA;
    unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(double) * size_A;
    h_A = (double*)mxGetData(mA);

    unsigned int size_B = matrix_size.uiWB * matrix_size.uiHB;
    unsigned int mem_size_B = sizeof(double) * size_B;
    h_B = (double*)mxGetData(mB);

    unsigned int size_C = matrix_size.uiWC * matrix_size.uiHC;
    unsigned int mem_size_C = sizeof(double) * size_C;

    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, C_sz, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    h_C = (double*)mxGetData(plhs[0]);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, mem_size_A);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, mem_size_B);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, mem_size_B, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, mem_size_C);

    matrixMultiply(d_A, d_B, d_C, matrix_size);
    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, mem_size_C, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);      
}


void matrixMultiply(double const* d_A, double const* d_B, double* d_C, sMatrixSize &matrix_size)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    const double alpha = 1.0f;
    const double beta = 0.0f;
    cublasDgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, matrix_size.uiWB, matrix_size.uiHA, matrix_size.uiWA, &alpha, d_B, matrix_size.uiWB, d_A, matrix_size.uiWA, &beta, d_C, matrix_size.uiWB);
    cublasDestroy(handle);
}
```