# cuBLAS Dgemm product with python

Tags: python, matrix, cuda, pycuda, cublas

I have `2` simple matrices `A` and `B` and I'm calculating their multiplication.
The arrays looks like this (using `numpy` as as mockup)

```
A=np.array(([1,2,3],[4,5,6])).astype(np.float64)
B=np.array(([7,8],[9,10],[11,12])).astype(np.float64)
```

Here are the shapes of the Matrix

```
A: (2, 3)

B: (3, 2)
```

Now, I am trying to do this using [cublasDgemmBatched](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemmbatched) to get the product.

I am confused on what my *m,n*,and *k* values should be when applying `cublasDgemmBatched`.
Also, I'm not sure what my leading dimension (`lda`, `ldb`, `ldc`) of the array would be.

There is a [nice 3d example](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda/blob/7e7300474286019c917a6c8a4bca59405c64fbce/tests/test_cublas.py#L531) here but I can't seem to get this function to work on 2d matrices.

Ideally, i would like to get the same results as [np.dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: It might be because the batched gemm is for an array of two dimensional matrices (or what you have called three dimensional matrices). If you really insist on using gemmbatched for a two dimensional array then for your example: `m = 2, n = 2, k = 3, lda = 3, ldb = 2, ldc = 2`. Although I cannot say with confidence whether or not this will work. Or, referencing the example you linked to, just set `l=1`.

Comment: You might want to be a little more explicit about what you mean by the dot product of 2 matrices.  matlab's [definition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) indicates a set of dot products of the matrix columns.  The implication is the matrices would have the same shape. If you indeed want a set of individual dot products of matrix columns, using batched gemm is probably not the way to go, since it is fairly [compilicated to set up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743384) and using a matrix product for a vector dot-product is overkill I think

Comment: I would like to get the same results as np.dot()

Comment: Then you probably want to use `cublasDgemm`. Adjusting the 3D example to fit your 2D one might look like this `cublasDgemm(self.cublas_handle, 'n','n', 2, 2, 3, alpha, b_arr.gpudata, 2, a_arr.gpudata, 3, beta, c_arr.gpudata, 2)`

Comment: Thankyou. I would like to mark your response as an answer but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have skcuda.blas to confirm this. But a more complete example might look like

```
A = np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])).astype(np.float64)
B = np.array(([7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12])).astype(np.float64)

m, k = A.shape
k, n = B.shape

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(A)
b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(B)
c_gpu = gpuarray.empty((m, n), np.float64)

alpha = np.float64(1.0)
beta = np.float64(0.0)

a_arr = bptrs(a_gpu)
b_arr = bptrs(b_gpu)
c_arr = bptrs(c_gpu)

cublas_handle = cublas.cublasCreate()

cublas.cublasDgemm(cublas_handle, 'n','n',
                   n, m, k, alpha,
                   b_arr.gpudata, m,
                   a_arr.gpudata, k,
                   beta, c_arr.gpudata, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to imitate `np.dot()` is using `culinalg.dot()` which uses `cuBLAS` behind, see [`skcuda.linalg.dot`](https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skcuda.linalg.dot.html). Below, a simple example:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy as np

import skcuda.linalg as culinalg
import skcuda.misc as cumisc
culinalg.init()

A = np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])).astype(np.float64)
B = np.array(([7, 8, 1, 5], [9, 10, 0, 9], [11, 12, 5, 5])).astype(np.float64)

A_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(A)
B_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(B)

C_gpu = culinalg.dot(A_gpu, B_gpu)

print(np.dot(A, B))
print(C_gpu)
```