# CUBLAS batch and matrix sizes

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, cublas

I am wondering what is considered reasonable sized matrices and batches for the various CUBLAS batched routines.

For example, the CUBLAS [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-getrsbatched) for `cublas<t>getrsBatched()` states:

> This function is intended to be used for matrices of small sizes where
>   the launch overhead is a significant factor.

Small is not too descriptive.  Maybe 'small' depends on the particular GPU model (e.g. GTX 580, TITAN X, K80)?

Another example is given in one of the answers linked below:

[How performing multiple matrix multiplications in CUDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743384/how-performing-multiple-matrix-multiplications-in-cuda)

They mention matrices and batch sizes that are "small", "moderate", and "large"; but it is not clear to me what this means exactly.

Ideally I would like an upper bound and lower bound on the sizes.  In the application I am working with the matrices are always smaller than the batch size - the matrices are of size 300x300 or smaller, and batch sizes are anywhere from 1,000 to 1,000,000.

**EDIT--------:**

I'm still not quite grasping the size issue.  Let me fix a concrete example.  Suppose we have 1,000,000 matrices all of size 300x300, and we want to invert them independently.

Say we have a GPU with 16 SMs.  Then by the definition given in the first comment below, (2048*16)/(300*300) < 0.37; so a 300x300 matrix is not small.  We can conclude I should not use the cuBLAS batched routines in this case (I think).  What strategies should I look into then?

Comment: One possible definition is a matrix, for which, if we assigned one thread per matrix element, the resulting threads would be much less than the instantaneous capacity of the GPU you are running on, which is 2048*(# of SMs) for newer GPUs. So we are probably in the range of 100x100 or smaller. It may depend on the GPU you intend to run on. The definition given in the cublas doc is a pretty good one - you seemed to have skipped right over it. If the duration of the resultant non-batched function call with the size of matrix is approximately on the order of the kernel launch overhead, it is small

Comment: @RobertCrovella  Thanks, I understand the definition better.  It looks like I have some testing to do.  For larger matrices that are not suitable for the batched routines, should I start by looking at a cuBLAS+stream type approach?  Or if the batch size is large and the matrix is also large, is the problem just not suited for the GPU any longer?

Comment: If a matrix fills the capacity of the GPU, streams are not likely to provide much benefit.  Large problems are usually well suited for the GPU, you seem to be confused about that.

Comment: Yes, I think I am still confused.

Comment: for matrix inversion of a lot of 300x300 matrices using your example, the cublas routines you might use in the batch case are getrfBatched and getriBatched. Since we are supposing that 300x300 is not small, then a straightforward approach would be to use a non-batched inversion method in a for loop iteration, iterating one-by-one over your 1,000,000 matrices. Once your basic work operation gets to an efficient level on the machine, you shouldn't need to batch it to get a reasonable level of efficiency. Also, streams might be useful here not to overlap kernels, but to overlap copy and compute.

Comment: Ahh I see.  I will play around with getrs from the cuSOLVER library.

Comment: @user107904 Matrix inversion is rarely the right approach numerically or from a performance perspective, usually one would want to use a solver. I agree with Robert Crovella that small matrices suitable for batched operations would typically be smaller than 100x100. Large matrices on the other hand would be those for which ordinary non-batched BLAS operations work with high efficiency. I'd say those start at around size 512x512. Sizes in between are "moderate". Significance of launch overhead is dependent on data type: e.g. complex is more numerically intensive than real, thus overhead smaller