# Getting pointers to specific elements of a 1D contiguous array on the device

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, cublas

I am trying to use CUBLAS in C++ to rewrite a python/tensorflow script which is operating on batches of input samples (of shape BxD, B: BatchSize, D: Depth of the flattened 2D matrix)

For the first step, I decided to use CUBLAS `cublasSgemmBatched` to compute MatMul for batches of matrices.

I've found couple working sample codes as the one in [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743838/8296604), 
but what I want is to allocate one big contiguous device array to store batches of flattened identical shaped matrices. I DO NOT want to store batches separated from each other on device memory(as they are in the provided sample code in the given link to StackOverflow question)

From what I can imagine, somehow I have to get a list of pointers to starting elements of each batch on device memory. something like this:

```
float **device_batch_ptr;
cudaMalloc((void**)&device_batch_ptr, batch_size*sizeof(float *));
for(int i = 0 ; i < batch_size; i++ ) {
    // set device_batch_ptr[i] to starting point of i'th batch on device memory array.
}
```

Note that `cublasSgemmBatched` needs a float** that each float* in it, points to starting element of each batch in a given input matrix.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arrays are in contiguous linear memory (`device_array`) then all you need to do is calculate the offsets using standard pointer arithmetic and store the device addresses in a host array which you then copy to the device. Something like:

```
float** device_batch_ptr;
float** h_device_batch_ptr = new float*[batch_size];

cudaMalloc((void**)&device_batch_ptr, batch_size*sizeof(float *));
size_t nelementsperrarray = N * N;
for(int i = 0 ; i < batch_size; i++ ) {
    // set h_device_batch_ptr[i] to starting point of i'th batch on device memory array.
    h_device_batch_ptr[i] = device_array + i * nelementsperarray;
}
cudaMemcpy(device_batch_ptr, h_device_batch_ptr, batch_size*sizeof(float *)),
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

[Obviously never compiled or tested, use at own risk]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to do this with cudaMemSet but memory alignment was a big problem. I tried your suggestion and it worked well, but I think we don't need `sizeof(float)` in `nbytesperarray` as pointers are of type float*. right?

Comment: Yes you're correct about the size. That was me starting to write an answer for a pitched array not linear memory and then changing my mind half way through. I wrote this on a subway train in my phone, the disclaimer is there for a reason.... But glad to help.