# Iterating over array of vectors with cuBLAS

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, cublas

I have a rotation matrix that I would like to apply to an array of vectors with cuBLAS. **How do I efficiently iterate over an array of vectors and run the cuBLAS matrix-vector multiplication function?**

From examples and documentation for cuBLAS I understand how to do matrix-vector multiplication given a matrix created as a pointer and a single input and output vector:

```
float* myMatrix;
cudaMallocManaged(&myMatrix, N*N*sizeof(float));

float* inputVector;
float* outputVector;

cudaMallocManaged(&inputVector, N*sizeof(float));
cudaMallocManaged(&outputVector, N*sizeof(float));
```

But nowhere does it explain how to accomplish this if `inputVector` was a 2D array (particularly, how do I write my results to a 2D `outputVector`).

It would also be great if someone could show how I could do this in a kernel since this process is pretty parallelizable. I don't really understand how to use cuBLAS in a kernel and have been using CPU for-loops (which are slow when `inputVector` gets large).

Please let me know how I can accomplish this!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you would use a [batched function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#blas-like-extension) such as [batched GEMM](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-GemmBatchedEx).  In current versions of CUDA (10.x, 11.x) you cannot call cublas functions from GPU kernel code.  The way to get parallel operation is to do a batched operation in CUBLAS. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743384) is a completely worked example which even covers the case you have where one of the input matrices is common across the batch.  Your question is arguably a duplicate of that one.

Comment: "don't really understand how to use cuBLAS in a kernel"  -- you should assume you can't do that. It had been deprecated/removed from recent versions

Comment: @ Robert Crovella: Thanks for the pointer on batched function, I'll take a look at your answer. I'm going to leave the question open though until I resolve my code. @talonmies: I got conflicting info about that (I'm a new CUDA programmer btw, just learning). An Nvidia forum did say it was deprecated, yet another post said you could still call cuBLAS functions in a kernel and I did so without problem (they were just really slow)